# lightning:inputfield - lookup field not working in Lightning Out - Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-out, lightning-recordeditform, lookup-field

I had a requirement, where I have to create a basic form so that users can have the functionality to create contact at the List view using a custom button. 
I have created a Aura Component and used the recordEditForm & embedded that component in VF so that a button can be created and added at the List View Search Layout.

I have a "AccountId" Lookup Field  which is working fine if I am using it as a standalone Quick Action in lightning, while using the same aura component in Salesforce1 its not showing as lookup.

KnownIssue Link: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dom1AAC
Salesforce Documentation: "The lookup type is supported in Lightning Experience only. When used in the mobile app, the lookup type is rendered as an input text field. Dependent lookups are not supported."

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation

Does anyone knows any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no workaround for this. `lightning:recordEditForm` is not supported (per documentation) in VF lightning out. What is your requirement where you have to show something on the mobile and that you are wrapping it on a VF? Why are you not directly displaying that as a lightning component on mobile?

Comment: Hi Jayant, the requirement is to have a button at list view which will help to create the records like contact with bare minimum required fields. I have checked for various options like QuickAction, Flow, URL (Out of the Box) functionalities, however these options are not available for Salesforce1 app i.e. you can only add a VF button or a Url button only to the search layout so that it is available for salesforce1 and this is the reason I have wrapped my aura component into an VF using LightningOut. Now the issue is that recordEditForm/recordForm does not support lookup fields in Salesforce1.